# Debian 11, networking service starts but not working

Tags: linux, debian, networking, services, winetricks

after installing directplay on winetricks my networking service is not working, i deleted the setup file in **/etc/network/interfaces.d** and changes my **/etc/network/interfaces to**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

But still not working

Comment: so what's managing the network? dhcpcd? NetworkManager? systemd-networkd? something else?

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry, I'm new in linux, i don't know what is managing my network, but i can see in /etc/ a folder called NetworkManager, I suppose it should be that.